# Connection pooling in the MySQL .NET Connector

Tags: .net, mysql

I'm creating a website in asp.net and mysql, I noticed that the performance of connection pooling in the mysql .net connector is horrible to say the least! For example sql server is 10x times faster in connection pooling (the sql server .net provider connecting to sql server), is there anything I could do to speed up connection pooling? Does the mysql .net connector make any checks when the connection is returned to the pool which cause the slowdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the latest version of MySQL .Net Connector. The current version is 5.2.5.

Also, the Connection String has a property Connection Lifetime (default value 0). You can try changing that value. More information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-using-connection-pooling.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectionstring)